# Pointers and/or functions not working correctly

Tags: c, function, pointers

Attempting to run this code will display blank inputs for most of the fields and will be mixed up, for example the street number would be in place of first name. Not sure what's going on. Was hesitant about using stackoverflow at first but now it seems I have no choice

header file:

```
// Structure type Name declaration
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};

// Structure type Address declaration
struct Address {
    int streetNumber;
    char street[41];
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};


// Structure type Numbers declaration
struct Numbers {
    char cell[11];
    char home[11];
    char business[11];
};


// Structure type Contact declaration
struct Contact {
    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    struct Numbers numbers;
};


//------------------------------------------------------
// Function Prototypes
//------------------------------------------------------

// Get and store from standard input the values for Name
void getName(struct Name* name);


// Get and store from standard input the values for Address
void getAddress(struct Address* address);


// Get and store from standard input the values for Numbers
void getNumbers(struct Numbers* numbers);
```

input file

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include "contacts.h"

//This function will clear the input buffer after every input
void clear() {
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}


// Get and store from standard input the values for Name
void getName(struct Name* name) {

    char option = 0;

    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf("%31s", name[0].firstName);
    clear();

    printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%c", &option);
    clear();

    if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's middle initial(s): ");
        scanf("%7[^\n]s", name[0].middleInitial);
        clear();
    }

    printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
    scanf("%36[^\n]s", name[0].lastName);
    clear();
}


// Get and store from standard input the values for Address
void getAddress(struct Address* address) {

    char option = 0;

    printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");
    scanf("%d", &address[0].streetNumber);
    clear();

    printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
    scanf("%40[^\n]s", address[0].street);
    clear();

    printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%c", &option);
    clear();

    if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
        scanf("%d", &address[0].apartmentNumber);
        clear();
    }

    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
    scanf("%7[^\n]s", address[0].postalCode);
    clear();

    printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
    scanf("%40[^\n]s", address[0].city);
    clear();
}


// Get and store from standard input the values for Numbers
void getNumbers(struct Numbers* numbers) {

    char option = 0;

    printf("Do you want to enter a cell phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%c", &option);
    clear();

    if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        scanf("%11s", numbers[0].cell);
        clear();
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%c", &option);
    clear();

    if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf("%11s", numbers[0].home);
        clear();
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%c", &option);
    clear();

    if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf("%11s", numbers[0].business);
        clear();
    }
}
```

my main program:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include "contacts.h"


int main(void)
{

    // Declare variables:
    struct Contact contact[] = {{0}};


        // Display the title
        printf("Contact Management System\n");
        printf("-------------------------\n");


        // Call the Contact function getName to store the values for the Name member
        getName(contact);

        // Call the Contact function getAddress to store the values for the Address member
        getAddress(contact);

        // Call the Contact function getNumbers to store the values for the Numbers member
        getNumbers(contact);

    // Display Contact summary details
    printf("\n");
    printf("Contact Details\n");
    printf("===============\n");
    printf("Name Details\n");
    printf("------------\n");
    printf("First name: %s\n", contact[0].name.firstName);
    printf("Middle initial(s): %s\n", contact[0].name.middleInitial);
    printf("Last name: %s\n", contact[0].name.lastName);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Address Details\n");
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf("Street number: %d\n", contact[0].address.streetNumber);
    printf("Street name: %s\n", contact[0].address.street);
    printf("Apartment: %d\n", contact[0].address.apartmentNumber);
    printf("Postal code: %s\n", contact[0].address.postalCode);
    printf("City: %s\n", contact[0].address.city);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Phone Numbers\n");
    printf("-------------\n");
    printf("Cell phone number: %s\n", contact[0].numbers.cell);
    printf("Home phone number: %s\n", contact[0].numbers.home);
    printf("Business phone number: %s\n", contact[0].numbers.business);
    printf("\n");


    // Display Completion Message
    printf("Structure test for Contact using functions done!\n");

    return 0;

}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: You have done a good thing by using header files containing function prototypes. Your compiler should be giving you warning/error messages. Take just the first one and work on that. (A mistake can trigger multiple warnings and sometimes only the first message of a series is meaningful,)

Comment: @AviBerger Honestly, the compiler errors don't even make sense to me. It displays something like this: https://pastebin.com/EnyUZZiN. I've tried many things but it either ends up messing up the code more or not doing anything.

Comment: @Zelkop this is because you are passing `contacts` of type `struct Contact *` to the function which expects `struct Name*` Fix it.

Comment: @Serge Sort of vague but the answer fixed the issue, thanks though

Comment: You need to work through to understanding those messages. Sometimes it is tough, but what you are seeing in your linked image would be considered very clear. It is pointing out a problem with your call to getName(). It says that the argument (parameter) is messed up - that what you are providing here is a pointer to a struct Contact, but what getName requires is a pointer to a struct Name.

Comment: @AviBerger yeah i feel kinda dumb for not really understanding it however i am sort of a newbie, i realize exactly whats wrong now as well , ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an error in main when calling your functions

```
getName(contact);
getAddress(contact);
getNumbers(contact);
```

your passing a contact struct while they wait for other structure types.

```
void getName(struct Name* name);
void getAddress(struct Address* address);
void getNumbers(struct Numbers* numbers);
```

try to correct this with

```
getName(&contact->name);
getAddress(&contact->address);
getNumbers(&contact->numbers);
```

Comment: Ayee yeah, I didn't even know those arrows were a thing, thanks a lot

Comment: Take some time to learn how to access struct elements.
In short if you work with a struct, use the dot notation ( contact.name ), but if you work with a pointer to a struct you have to use the "arrow" notation (contact->name).